# Is it possible to use Integers and Strings as cases in a switch case?

Tags: java, string, integer, switch-statement

I've done some looking around and haven't really found much direct info on this so I'd like to just ask it directly.

Is it possible to use integers and strings in a switch case? I know the switch is of one type (int, string, etc), but is there a way around it? For example:

```
int list;

switch(list)
{
     case 1: ...code...
             break;
     case 2: ...code...
             break;
     case XY: ...code...
             break;
}
```

I know this would throw an error of mismatched data. But is it possible to work around the error? Would something like Integer.toString() work to convert the int to a string? Just want to get some thoughts and information on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this that should work even on older versions of Java and doesn't require the use of preview features from the latest versions is to combine the use of `instanceof` and `switch`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add("XY");
        list.add(3);
        list.add("test");
        for (var element : list) {
            if (element instanceof Integer) {
                Integer element2 = (Integer) element;
                switch (element2) {
                    case 1: System.out.println(1); break;
                    case 2: System.out.println(2); break;
                    default: System.out.println("Not 1 or 2"); 
                }
            }
            if (element instanceof String) {
                String element3 = (String) element;
                switch (element3) {
                    case "XY": System.out.println("XY"); break;
                    default: System.out.println("NOT XY");
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Output:**

*1*

*2*

*XY*

*Not 1 or 2*

*NOT XY*

Comment: Of what type is the arraylist when declaring it just with var? Object?

Comment: Good catch, that doesn't have to be `var` (should be `List` instead, I'll change it now), as that won't work with older versions of Java. But no, notice that it's instantiated as `ArrayList`, so that will be the type. `var` only works on Java 10 or later, and it instructs the compiler to infer the type from the value on the right side of the assignment operator.

Comment: thanks, I knew that. But I asked the wrong question. What I really meant is: Of what type is the generic argument of the list when declaring it this way - Object? Does the new solution work without the generic argument? E. G. : List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>() ;

Comment: It should be Object, yes, given that you can add values of type String and of type Integer, and Object is the first common ancestor of both of those types.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called pattern matching for switch statements. This is a feature that has been offered with Java 17 as you can see [here](https://openjdk.org/jeps/406). However, this feature is still in preview. With that in mind you could modify your code to look like so, and then enable preview features in order to make it work. An example would be:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
  var list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(1);
  list.add(2);
  list.add("test");
  for (var element : list) {
     var result = switch (element) {
     case Integer i -> i * 2;
     case String s -> String.format("This is a formatted string %s", s);
     default -> element;
     };
     System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

And then enabled preview features when compiling.

Comment: is that something like using generics in a switch statement?

Comment: Nope. Check the link posted in the answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well this approach is not possible, it has to be same data type
But you can to this

Try to convert the int to string then you will be fine.

```
int list;

  switch(list.toString()){
    case "1": ...code...
         break;
    case "2": ...code...
         break;
    case "XY": ...code...
         break;
    default: ....code...
          break;
  }
```

Comment: In this example the "XY" case will never run, because there's no way to `toString()` a value of type `int` and get "XY" as a result. So while this might compile, it doesn't really solve the problem if we assume OP wants the "XY" case to be executable. One might as well not use `toString()` and delete the unreachable branch, as the effect will be the same.

Comment: well I don't have the data, can be a list of Any. but believed he asked for a reason

Comment: It's not even a list though. Just an `int` that for some reason is called `list`. And my point still stands that that branch is unreachable... Unless `list` is of type `String`, in which case you don't need `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it will work.

It depends on your jdk, because the switch statement has been "tuned" a few times. If you can "compare" a String in a switch statement, then this will work and the stage is yours.

I looked it up, you need at least jdk7.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Convert the ints to String like this:

```
int x = 5; 
String intString = x + "" ;  //string concatenation or StringBuilder, your choice


  switch(intString){
    case "1": ...code...
         break;
    case "2": ...code...
         break;
    case "XY": ...code...
         break;
    default: ....code...
          break;
  }
```

Sorry for the many edits, I just hate my smartphone.

Comment: Obviously this doesn't compile. But if we assume the missing variable name, there's no way starting with an 'int

Comment: Yes you are right, I was confused because of my smartphone. It must be "int number = 5" and not "int =5". Shame on me. Thanks for the correction, I accepted it!

Comment: Would this not cause a type mismatch error?

Comment: No, because there is no type mismatch when comparing two strings. It makes no difference when comparing "hello" with "hello", "12 years" with "12 years" or "12" with "12". The case "XY" will just never be called because the intString is just a string version of an int. So it will never be "XY".

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum.

Pay attention to the following code example:

```
public enum MethodClick {
    Error,
    OnClick,
    OnDelete
}

  MethodClick methodClick;
    switch (methodClick){
        case Error:
            break;
        case OnClick:
            break;
        case OnDelete:
    }
```